# Java Startup Exception Error

Tags: java, internet-explorer-11

I am new to Java (Sorry if this question has been posed before).

I know the applications are no long supported below but I am just after guidance.

We have a closed network and the applications we use are very legacy.

I am currently running IE11 and Java 8 update 25 32bit and when trying to launch and application I get an error message:

[Startup exeception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdhjZ.png)

I have the log below:

```
Java Plug-in 11.25.2.18
Using JRE version 1.8.0_25-b18 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\mmahmood
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------
java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    com.cramer.core.common.CramerRuntimeException caused by com.cramer.core.common.CramerException ,FaultID=179C829066D456DD25365222F8B,Message=Unable to create a connection: java.sql.SQLException: Request timed out; no connection available
    at com.cramer.core.server.CramerConnectionManagerImpl.createBaseConnection(CramerConnectionManagerImpl.java:149)
    at com.cramer.core.server.CramerConnectionManagerImpl.createConnection(CramerConnectionManagerImpl.java:108)
    at com.cramer.core.server.CMTReadOnlyConnectionManager.getConnection(CMTReadOnlyConnectionManager.java:102)
    at com.cramer.core.server.CramerSessionBeanImpl.getConnection(CramerSessionBeanImpl.java:370)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.serviceimpl.BundleServiceImpl.getBundleFamily(BundleServiceImpl.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor550.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    at com.cramer.core.server.CramerSessionBeanImpl.performCoreSecurity(CramerSessionBeanImpl.java:99)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor528.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.MethodInvocationInvocationContext.proceed(MethodInvocationInvocationContext.java:101)
    at com.cramer.core.server.audit.AuditLoggingInterceptor.logInvocation(AuditLoggingInterceptor.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor527.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.oracle.pitchfork.intercept.JeeInterceptorInterceptor.invoke(JeeInterceptorInterceptor.java:94)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at com.bea.core.repackaged.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy364.getBundleFamily(Unknown Source)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.serviceimpl.BundleService_wknfa8_EOImpl.__WL_invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invokeInternal(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:54)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.internal.SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.invoke(SessionRemoteMethodInvoker.java:21)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.serviceimpl.BundleService_wknfa8_EOImpl.getBundleFamily(Unknown Source)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.serviceimpl.BundleService_wknfa8_EOImpl_WLSkel.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.ServerRequest.sendReceive(ServerRequest.java:250)
    at weblogic.rmi.internal.BasicRemoteRef.invoke(BasicRemoteRef.java:299)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.serviceimpl.BundleService_wknfa8_EOImpl_12213_WLStub.getBundleFamily(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1007.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cramer.core.axis.CramerStatelessBeanProvider$ServiceInvocationHandler.invokeStubMethod(CramerStatelessBeanProvider.java:140)
    at com.cramer.core.axis.CramerStatelessBeanProvider$ServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(CramerStatelessBeanProvider.java:113)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy363.getBundleFamily(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor609.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
    at com.cramer.core.axis.CramerRPCProvider.invokeMethod(CramerRPCProvider.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
    at com.cramer.core.axis.CramerRPCProvider.processMessage(CramerRPCProvider.java:94)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at com.cramer.core.sso.ApplicationFilter.doFilter(ApplicationFilter.java:134)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
    at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
    at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
    at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
 ,FaultID=179C829066FDFC67A5DC11B1779,Message=com.cramer.core.common.CramerException ,FaultID=179C829066D456DD25365222F8B,Message=Unable to create a connection: java.sql.SQLException: Request timed out; no connection available
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.cramer.core.proxy.MappedServiceDispatcher.mappedThrowable(MappedServiceDispatcher.java:329)
    at com.cramer.core.axisclient.SOAPServiceDispatcher.mappedThrowable(SOAPServiceDispatcher.java:313)
    at com.cramer.core.proxy.MappedServiceDispatcher.invoke(MappedServiceDispatcher.java:266)
    at com.cramer.core.axisclient.SOAPServiceDispatcher.invoke(SOAPServiceDispatcher.java:122)
    at com.cramer.core.axisclient.SOAPServiceDispatcher$1.execute(SOAPServiceDispatcher.java:94)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.ActionWithClassLoader.executeWithException(ActionWithClassLoader.java:80)
    at com.cramer.core.axisclient.SOAPServiceDispatcher.invoke(SOAPServiceDispatcher.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.getBundleFamily(Unknown Source)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.service.BundleManagerHelper.getBundlesFromBundleService(BundleManagerHelper.java:212)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.service.BundleManagerHelper.getCramerResourceBundle(BundleManagerHelper.java:120)
    at com.cramer.core.framework.service.BundleManagerHelper.getBundle(BundleManagerHelper.java:91)
    at com.cramer.core.client.ClientBundleManagerImpl.getBundle(ClientBundleManagerImpl.java:70)
    at com.cramer.core.client.g11n.CramerFormatter.<init>(CramerFormatter.java:111)
    at com.cramer.core.client.g11n.CramerFormatter.<init>(CramerFormatter.java:85)
    at com.cramer.core.client.g11n.CramerFormatter.<init>(CramerFormatter.java:74)
    at com.cramer.core.client.ServiceManager.initExceptionMessages(ServiceManager.java:296)
    at com.cramer.core.client.ServiceManager.initialize(ServiceManager.java:233)
    at com.cramer.core.client.CramerApplet.init(CramerApplet.java:219)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.CramerAppletWrapper.init(CramerAppletWrapper.java:115)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.CramerContainerApplet.initChild(CramerContainerApplet.java:761)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.CramerContainerApplet.access$700(CramerContainerApplet.java:78)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.CramerContainerApplet$4.execute(CramerContainerApplet.java:748)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.CramerContainerApplet$4.execute(CramerContainerApplet.java:745)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.ActionWithClassLoader$1.run(ActionWithClassLoader.java:95)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.ActionWithClassLoader.executeWithException(ActionWithClassLoader.java:89)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.ActionWithClassLoader.execute(ActionWithClassLoader.java:140)
    at com.cramer.core.boot.ActionWithClassLoader$1EventThreadRunnable.run(ActionWithClassLoader.java:167)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Jun 01, 2021 4:20:34 PM com.cramer.core.client.g11n.CramerFormatter <init>
WARNING: No BundleService bundle for CoreClient: falling back to a local ResourceBundle
java.rmi.RemoteException: EJB Exception: ; nested exception is: 
    com.cramer.core.common.CramerRuntimeException caused by com.cramer.core.common.CramerException ,FaultID=179C829686B195CC15F931534EE,Message=Unable to create a connection: java.sql.SQLException: Request timed out; no connection available
    at com.cramer.core.server.CramerConnectionManagerImpl.createBaseConnection(CramerConnectionManagerImpl.java:149)
```

There was a lot more code but it seemed  to be repetitive.

I have picked this up from the code:

**FaultID=179C829066D456DD25365222F8B,Message=Unable to create a connection: java.sql.SQLException: Request timed out; no connection available**

Seems like there is no problem with the Java installed on the Server but a connection failure?

I just need your advice please before I send this to the applicaiton team incase they push back on system setup.

Lastly the application I am trying to run is in development.

Comment: Is this from an Java applet or a Java WebStart application?

Comment: Your application is failing because it's unable to make the connection to the database.  The fact the application is crashing with a JavaVM error means the application is actually executing.

Comment: Sorry guys I found out what the issue was @Ramhound you are correct I was using an incorrect protocol I was using HTTP when I should be using HTTP and the port number was also incorrect. I was being lazy and typing in the URL where I should of copied the URL on USB and copied an pasted on the closed network. Robert it is Java applet but the problem no longer exists thanks for you input guys.